# How can I use carrierwave with Rmagick to resize both a horizontal and vertical image accordingly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I want my app to be able to tell the difference between a horizontal image and a vertical image, and resize it accordingly when the user uploads it.

I was able to get it working with minimagick but for some reason it does not work the same with Rmagick below is the logic I used for minimagick (in the initializers/carrierwave.rb)

*I need to switch to rmagick for some other features I'd like to use*

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

module CarrierWave
    module RMagick
        def from_orientation(portrait, landscape)
            manipulate! do |img|
                if img[:width] > img[:height]
                    width, height = landscape
                else
                    width, height = portrait
                end
                img.resize "#{width}x#{height}>"
                img
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see i changed the module from minimagick to rmagick I also included the proper gem as well. This is the error i get which makes me wonder what exactly I'm doing wrong:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

This confuses me because the greater than bracket is obviously not a class.

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is RMagick and MiniMagick have different interfaces. You can't just switch the library and expect the same code to work.

Your error is telling you the problem is that img[:width] is nil. This makes sense because img[:width] is not something you can do with RMagick. `img.columns` should give the width and likewise `img.rows` would give the height.

I recommend reviewing the documentation for RMagick.